# How to use a common GeoWebCache for multiple Geoservers?

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I had multiple Geoserver's (5) in different systems one is back up for another with same port and same layers are published . I know that every Geoserver is integrated with Geowebcache. Now I want to turn off individual GeoWebCache on every system and to install a new GeoWebCache  for all geoserver's on any system.How to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use one GeoWebCache installation which caches map layers from several GeoServer instances. I assume you read the documentation at: http://geowebcache.org/docs/1.5.1/introduction/whichgwc.html ?

If you use the standalone version, you have to define all layers manually whereas an integrated version takes automatically all defined layers from GeoServer. To define your layers, locate the file `geowebcache.xml` and add a new entry for each layer. Here an example from a custom layer in my GeoWebCache:

```
<wmsLayer>
  <name>census2005:literacy_rate_pct</name>
    <metaInformation>
      <title>Nicer title for Image States</title>
      <description>This is a description. Fascinating.</description>
    </metaInformation>
    <mimeFormats>
      <string>image/jpeg</string>
      <string>image/png</string>
      <string>image/png8</string>
    </mimeFormats>
    <gridSubsets>
      <gridSubset>
        <gridSetName>EPSG:900913</gridSetName>
        <extent>
          <coords>
            <double>10018754.167</double>
            <double>181.378</double>
            <double>12801601.740</double>
            <double>3482189.084</double>
          </coords>
        </extent>
      </gridSubset>
    </gridSubsets>
    <expireCacheList>
      <expirationRule minZoom="0" expiration="60" />
    </expireCacheList>
    <expireClientsList>
      <expirationRule minZoom="0" expiration="500" />
    </expireClientsList>
    <wmsUrl>
      <string>/charts/wms</string>
    </wmsUrl>
    <wmsLayers>census2005:literacy_rate_pct</wmsLayers>
    <transparent>true</transparent>
    <bgColor>0xFFFFFF</bgColor>
  </wmsLayer>
</layers>
```

In this case my custom-made web map server runs at the same host, but this can be any standard compatible web map server as GeoServer. See also the documentation for an explanation of all options: http://geowebcache.org/docs/1.5.1/configuration/layers/index.html

Comment: I believe that @iant is closer. Obviously users wants to configure 5 identical WMS sources to seed a single GWC layer and gain for load balancing.

Answer (score 3):

Just set up GWC on a machine and point it to the loadbalancer that controls access to your GeoServers. Then each tile request will be sent to the next available GeoServer in exactly the same way as your users are currently.

You should probably read this [series of posts](http://boundlessgeo.com/2013/04/geoserver-in-a-clustered-configuration-part-1/) before going much further.

Answer (score 1):

Ciao,
if you use a standalone GeoWebCache you can have a single tile layer backe by multiple WMS. Check this post for more information:
http://www.geo-solutions.it/blog/tips-tricks-geowebcache-tweaks-checklist/

If you use integrated GeoWebCache (integrated with GeoServer) then you may need to enable clustered diskquota support. Check the links below:

- http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/caching_data/index.html
- http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/clustering/index.html

Simone.